Countdown timer being skipped in my while loop logic and I am not exactly sure why
I am trying to print the latitude and longitude values from my GPS sensor at regular intervals of 1 second. I am trying to do this in the simplest way possible and included my basic code below (please ignore the formatting and variable names. My project is only a test to see if I can access phone sensors).
Within the onCreate method:
(I have all the required manifest and runtime permissions listed)
tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
while(true)
                {
                    System.out.println("in while");
                    //tv1.append("IN WHILE");  //PROBLEM 2
                    new CountDownTimer(1000, 500)
                    {
                        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
                        public void onFinish()
                        {
                            fusedLocationClient.getCurrentLocation(LocationRequest.QUALITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, cancellationTokenSource.getToken());
//                                    addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
//                                @Override
//                                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
//                                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
//                                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
//                                    System.out.println("LOCATION ACQUIRED!!!!!!!");
//                                }
//                            }).addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
//                                @Override
//                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
//                                    System.out.println("LOCATION FAILED!!!!!!!!!");
//                                }
//                            });
                            System.out.println("in timer 2"); //PROBLEM 1
                            tv1.append("IN timer 2");
                            workGPS();

                        }
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
                        {
//                              // millisUntilFinished    The amount of time until finished.
                        }
                    }.start();
                }

Two problems here:

"In timer" text is never printed. In the logs or on textview. This tells me that the countdowntimer is probably not entered.

The commented line tv1.append("IN WHILE"); throws an error of java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.append(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference.


I think problem 2 is an error from my side - not understanding some concepts well enough. But I am not sure about problem 1. Could you please help me understand what am I doing wrong?

Problem 1)
Not 100% clear but is your while(true) loop maybe blocking the main thread and thus the CountDownTimer is never executed?
You could try using a Handler which posts a runnable every X ms.
handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

runnable = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
      .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
          [...]
        }
      })
      .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
          [...]
        }
      });

    handler.postDelayed(this, 500);
  }
};

handler.post(runnable);

Don't forget handler.removeCallbacks(runnable) e.g. when activity is destroyed
Problem 2)
I guess tv1 is not initialized. Are you calling setContentView before findViewById?
